# Error importing databases in mysql: ERROR 1005 (HY000) (errno:-1)

Tags: mysql, linux, database, admin

I have a MySQL server (5.5.35) in debian wheezy. I have to import 12 databases from 12 dumps. The databases are identical except for their names (so are the dumps, of course), they have 108 tables and they are empty (so I'm just importing the schema, actually).

The problem is that there is a point when the imports start to fail with this error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'databasename.tablename' (errno: -1)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The most interesting thing is that it fails in a certain point, no matter which database I am importing: suppose that the databases are named from 1 to 12. The first 6 will be imported correctly, but when importing the seventh, it will eventually fail every time it tries to create a table with the afromentioned error. From this point, the rest of the imports will fail the same way. After removing everything and trying to import everything again, but in a different order (from 12 to 1), the databases 6-12 will be correctly imported, but the DB 5 will fail with the same error.

The fact that is failing in a certain point no matter what I'm trying to do suggest that I have reached some kind of limit. The only limit I know in MySQL is open_files_limit, which right now is set to 65535 (the maximum IIRC). The limits of the OS shown in the limits.conf show reasonable values.

I am completly lost. I don't have the slightest idea where is the problem. Clearly is not in the sql dumps, since it would have failed for every DB. I don't know if it's a problem in the mysql configuration, the OS, or what.

UPDATE: I have tried importing the same SQL dumps into another similar server (in my own computer, with MariaDB-5.5.37), and I had success. I have quickly checked the variables and parameters of both SQL servers, and while they are not identical, I haven't found anything suspicious.

Comment: Do you use InnoDB with a fixed-size data file? You might simply be running out of pages!

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I didn't install or configured the stuff in the server, and I don't have access to it right now. It may be, though, sounds reasonable. When I will check this in a near future. Edit: I don't know a lot about SQL and InnoDB, but I have the option "innodb_file_per_table" enabled. I don't know if it's related or not.

Comment: Look into the parameter `innodb_data_file_path` of the mysql config file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf or similar)

Comment: I don't have this parameter, so I guess is the default: "ibdata1:10M:autoextend". If I understand correctly, this wouldn't be a problem. The imported DB are just 10 Mb aprox.